# Use javascript variable in document.querySelector (howTo)

Tags: javascript, variables, queryselector

how can I replace the "16" by the javascript-variable "sixteen"?

```
var sixteen=16;
var span600=document.querySelector("body > app-root > app-home > main > app-chat > div > app-chat-list > div > ul > li:nth-child(16) > app-comment > div > div > div > button > span");
```

-Does it work if I use the javascript variable sixteen directly in the document.querySelector or do I have to convert the variable to a string using: sixteen.toString()

Comment: The same way you replace it in any other string. Either string concatenation or a template literal. Why would it be different in a query selector?

Comment: `var span600=document.querySelector(\`body > app-root > app-home > main > app-chat > div > app-chat-list > div > ul > li:nth-child(${sixteen}) > app-comment > div > div > div > button > span\`);`